# How to get element value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

Why is it not returning value in 'li'? What am i doing wrong?

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).val();
    alert(selected);
})
```

Comment: What are you trying to do ? What does your html list look like ?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Did you want the HTML or text that is inside the `li` tag?

If so, use either:

```
$(this).html()
```

or:

```
$(this).text()
```

The `val()` is for form fields only.

Comment: What do you mean of "form fields" ? Can you give me an example? tnx

Answer (score 7):

```
<ul id="unOrderedList">
<li value="2">Whatever</li>
.
.



 $('#unOrderedList li').click(function(){
      var value = $(this).attr('value');
     alert(value); 
  });
```

Your looking for the attribute "value" inside the "li" tag

Answer (score 3):

Use .text() or .html()

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
        var selected = $(this).text();
        alert(selected);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

A li doesn't have a value. Only form-related elements such as input, textarea and select have values.

Answer (score 2):

Most probably, you want something like this:

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
        var selected = $(this).html();
        alert(selected);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  <div class="inter">
      <p>Liste des Produits</p>
      <ul>
          <li><a href="#1">P1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#2">P2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#3">P3</a></li>
      </ul>
  </div>

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $(".inter li").bind(
            "click", function(){
                alert($(this).children("a").text());
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the same by using jQuery [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

```
$("#list").on('click','li',(function() {
    var selected = $(this).text();   //or .html()
    alert(selected);
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#list li").click(function() {
        var selected = $(this).html();
        alert(selected);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To get value of li we should use
$("#list li").click(function() {
    var selected = $(this).html();

or

```
var selected = $(this).text();

alert(selected);
```

})