# Getting child element's value of a partial HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

**Edited:** The following question is not original question. But @empiric's answer is right.

I can get value of element-assigned variable using vanilla JavaScript codes. 
How can I get it using `jQuery`?

my partial html is like the following;

```
<form class="ui-filterable">
    <input data-type="search" id="parentElement-filter" placeholder="Listede ara..." />
</form>

<ul data-role="listview" id="parentElement" data-filter="true" data-input="#parentElement-filter">
    <li>
        <h1> header-1 </h1>
        <p> paragraph-1 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1> header-2 </h1>
        <p> paragraph-2 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1> header-3 </h1>
        <p> paragraph-3 </p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h1> header-4 </h1>
        <p> paragraph-4 </p>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How to get a partial HTML element's value using jQuery? The following codes don't work.

```
var listItems = $("#parentElement");

$.each(parentElement, function(index, item) {

       var itemText = item.find("h1").text();
   // but this works= item.getElementsByTag("h1")[0].innerHTML;

       alert(itemText); 

});
```

**ps:** I was able to get value using `.find()` and `.children()` method but the method returned a ton value. I want to get pure data like JavaScript's result.

### Edit

This question's former subject is "Getting child element's value of an assigned jQuery variable"

The question's subject is wrong. It should have been "[Getting child element's value of a partial HTML using jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/jup6gszo/17/)"...

Thank you for your fast response @empiric and @DeeMac.
You're right...

First of all, when I was trying to make simple my question I made mistake. 
In fact, my problem that I couldn't catch header text in a $.each loop. 
Therefore It needs to wrap with `$("item").find("h1").text()` for each item in the loop.
like this http://jsfiddle.net/jup6gszo/17/

**As a result;**

`$(item).find('h1').text()` codes are more readable than `item.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML`

However `$(item).find('h1').text()` slower than `item.getElementsByTagName("h1")[0].innerHTML` if we use with intensive data (by the way this is a weird thinking for a mobile ui).
here are the results   http://jsperf.com/jquery-find-vs-getelementsbytagname

Thank you...

Comment: you can search using google which will give you a lot of examples

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get element value in jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/551538/how-to-get-element-value-in-jquery)

Comment: what output you want?

Comment: I've tried to catch a list item value in a loop. But I couldn't. And now I've edited my question and I've added the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right, you want something like the following:

```
parentElement = $('body');
text = parentElement.find('h1').text();
console.log(text);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jup6gszo/)**

**Reference:**

[.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood correctly, and you want the 'jquery version' of what you're currently doing with plain javascript see the following:

```
parentElement.find('h1').html();
```

More on jQuery find:

http://api.jquery.com/find/